# How to monitor the security patches for ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04, server, patch

I have joined the ubuntu desktop 18.04 LTS version to AD domain using Realmd and SSSD. My question is that do i have constantly monitor any security patch releases or any advise would be great help.

Regards,

BadriV

Comment: The system checks for security updates daily. So what is your question? I can't see how AD is related.

Answer (score 1):

You may be looking for [unattended updates](https://libre-software.net/ubuntu-automatic-updates/). This should automatically install not only security updates but just general package updates as well.

I have done this for my own servers when they may not be used or actively updated, so they should stay up to date on security and packages.

Comment: I have an environment about 20 Linux (Ubuntu) machines which are joined to the AD domain..we have disabled the updates as well upgrades on the client machines, so they do not auto update or upgrade. My questions is there any way i monitor the security updates through centralized server and push those updates to the clients after thorough testing?

Comment: I do not believe so, other than just looking at the website for recent updates.